# Add data to a legend, with different format? Or should I use a label?

Tags: highcharts

I am experimenting with the legend; trying to get as result, a panel where I display data about the chart.

I am planning to add the last value, and min and max.

Looking for some examples, and I found one that use a function called labelFormatter, altho I am not having luck in understanding how does it works.

I need to have values with different text color and different size, so I am not even sure if I can use the title of the legend for this purpose, or if I should hide the legend and create directly a label (altho the issue then is related to moving and resizing, right? Since the legend update its position if the chart window is resized).

Which is the best way to do what I am planning to do? a label or the legend?

Comment: Do you want to add text formatted with HTML code into the chart plot area ?

Comment: I think yes, otherwise I can't have different font size and color, is that correct? Tried with a Label and it may work, but I can't make its background transparent, so it will not stand out too much on the chart; that's why I am going for the Legend (but whatever method works is fine with me).

Comment: Do you consider a use of legend title to add custom text (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.title), in other scenarios you need to use renderer or labelFormatter with set useHTML (to customise colors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are considering adding HTML elements into the chart plot area then you will have to use **[Highcharts Renderer API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer)**.

You can refer this [JSFIDDLE working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/HW7Rm/)

it works like:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
....
.....
......
}, function(chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.text('This text is <span style="color: red">styled</span> and <a href="http://example.com">linked</a>', 150, 80)
        .css({
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px'
        })
        .add();

});
```

Comment: Happy to help you, newbiez ! Please consiser accepting the answer if that really helps, so the information can be useful to others also ! :)

Comment: I always wait a bit to give the best answer to see if anyone want to post; is not like I forgot :) Thanks again! Rendered is magic :)